# Sending messages from web page to another web page on the local system

Tags: javascript, html

So lets say there are two html pages : page1.html and page 2.html.

In the page one there will be a list of food items displayed with a check box to each food item. The total bill will be displayed in the corner. When the user clicks the order button , The food items list that the user selected and the total amount should be sent to page2.html.

I can code upto the design and calculating the total of the items that the user selected.

But how do i send them to the page2?

Comment: Pass values as url params and read in your second page. Refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-get-parameters

Comment: You could include the data in the request, such as with query string values or POST values (the latter generally requires server-side code as well).  Or you could persist the data in some storage medium, such as a cookie or Local Storage in the browser.

Comment: I want to avoid server side as much as possible, anyways i will try with the url parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numerous ways to do this but the easiest is to send them in the query string, such as:

```
http://localhost/page2.html?food1=hamburger&food2=fries
```